# How to write simple if condition in ash?

Tags: shell, shell-script, test, ash

I would like to write a small script that would check every once in a while if I have the internet connection. I would like to run it in `crontab` on my router where I have `ash`.

I am having a hard time using `ash` with if conditionals

So far I have gotten to something like this :

```
#!/bin/ash

echo $i
if [ $(ping -c 1 google.com) -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "IT WORKS :)"
else
  echo "no internet :( "
fi
```

But it gets me this error :

```
# ./restart_on_no_connection.sh 
ash: google.com: unknown operand
no internet
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I have no `ash` available for now, but I would try first with `if ping -c 1 google.com; then echo "IT WORKS :)"; else echo "no internet :( "; fi`. (Redirect `ping`'s output to /dev/null to silence it.)

Comment: @manatwork It works :) thanks a lot. You can submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understand `ash` to be Bourne-derived, so I think this should work:

```
if ping -c1 www.google.com > /dev/null; then
    echo "It worked"
else
    echo "No dice"
fi
```